# AjaxMin4 bug with Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxmin

When I compile my solution I get 2 errors which I did not get with version of 1.1 of AjaxMin.

The "SourceFiles" parameter is not supported by the "AjaxMin" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.

The "AjaxMin" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.

If I re-install AjaxMin4 then reload VS it works again until I reboot the PC.

Is this a known issue and is there a fix?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. But the weird thing is that in my dev box (win7) it works fine. If we try to build in the build machine (windows server 2003) it gives me this error. I tried to install/uninstall and reboot but no luck. My advise? YUI Compressor (http://bit.ly/AWec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use JsSourceFiles key name instead of SourceFiles.

In general try something like this:

```
<AjaxMin  JsSourceFiles="@(JsFilesDevelopment)" 
          JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" 
          JsTargetExtension=".js" 
          CssSourceFiles="@(CssFilesDevelopment)"
          CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$"
          CssTargetExtension=".css"/>
```